# Date formatting is lost after putting it to CSV file

Tags: java, date, csv, simpledateformat

I have some date, which I need to put into CSV file. I formatted the date to String using simple date format. By using debugger I found out that it works, date is really formatted correctly.

However after putting it into CSV file I get format dd-MM-yyyy HH:ss and I wanted yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss.

Here is the code:

```
    if (x.Contact_Email_IsSubscribed.equals("False")) {
                    //boolean merged = false;
                    Date latestUnsubscriptionDate=new Date(0);
                    // MERGE UNSUBSCRIBED DATE WITH CONTACT
                    for (Contact y : unsubscribedContacts) {
                        if (y.EmailAddress.equals(x.C_EmailAddress)) {
                            //find latest unsubscription date
                            Date unsubscriptionDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm").parse(y.ActivityDate);
                            //System.out.println(unsubscriptionDate);
                            if 
(unsubscriptionDate.compareTo(latestUnsubscriptionDate)>0){
                                latestUnsubscriptionDate=unsubscriptionDate;
                                //System.out.println();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    values.append(x.toString() + ";" + new 
 SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(latestUnsubscriptionDate));
                    values.append("\n");
                } else {
                    values.append(x.toString() + ";null" + "\n");
                }
```

And to the CSV file it is simply written like this:

```
    writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
    writer.append(values.toString());
```

It is driving me crazy.

Comment: Is the System.out printing correct value?

Comment: i'm assuming that the CSV is written as you expected. Try opening it in a text editor instead of excel, the latter auto-formats dates in that format

Comment: @lock you are right ... hell, I spent so much time on it. I feel very stupid now. Thank you. Is there any way how to avoid excel incorrect formatting? Btw please answer so I can mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you open it as simple text file does it keep your format yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss ?

It might be due to the software you use which change automatically the format of your string recognized as a date to a default one.

Comment: Check comments @lock has already answered the question and he was right, after you saw he was right you used it to answer...

Comment: either way, @lock did not post it as an answer.